# How to get data based on userId from firebase Android kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch data from firebase based on userId, when the user logged in I need to show his profile details based on its id but I am unable to fetch it. Any help?

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/")
        databaseRef.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                //I want first_name and all other details of users
                Log.e("first_name", snapshot.child(uid).getValue(String::class.java))
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

        })
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that you don't seem to initialize `uid` anywhere. So that should be:

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
uid = auth.currentUser.uid
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

---

Next is not necessarily a bug, but definitely an optimization you'll want to do. Right now you read the entire `Users` node into your Android app, to then only get a value from `/Users/$uid`. As you add more users to the database, this is not going to scale.

What you'll want to do instead, is *only* load the node for the current user from the database with:

```
databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/")
var userRef = databaseRef.child(uid)
userRef.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        Log.e("first_name", snapshot.getValue(String::class.java))
    }
    ...
```